# Extending morphisms from theta divisor to Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a very general curve of genus $g$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $x_0\in X(\mathbb{C})$ be a closed point.

Let $\Theta\subset\mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ be the theta divisor. Let $f:\Theta\to\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ be its translation to $\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ by tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_X((1-g)x_0)$.

Do we know if every $g\in \mathrm{Mor}(\Theta, \mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}})$ is necessarily of the form $g=\tau\circ [n]\circ f$, where $[n]$ is the multiplication map on $\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}$, and $\tau$ is some translation on $\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/k}$?

(Or equivalently, do we know if every $g\colon \Theta\subset \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_{X/\mathbb{C}}\to\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}$ necessarily extends to some morphism $\widetilde{g}\colon \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_{X/\mathbb{C}}\to\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X/\mathbb{C}}$?)

Comment: Just restrict the morphism to a translate of the curve (by an effective divisor of degree $g-2$) inside $\Theta$.  Every morphism from the curve to its Albanese factors through a unique self-map of the Albanese, by the universal property of the Albanese.

Comment: I would even say that $\mathrm{Alb}(\Theta) = \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ and $f$ is the Albanese morphism. So any morphism from $\Theta$ to $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ factors as $f$ followed by an endomorphism of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$.

Comment: Let $\Theta$ be covered by translates of the curve $X_a=\tau_a(X)$ with $a\in\mathrm{Div}^{g−2}(X)$,
I am a bit confused why would the families of morphisms $g|_{X_{\alpha}}\colon X_\alpha\overset{alb}{\to}\mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_{X_a}\to\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X}$ 
fit into some $\Theta\to \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_X\to\mathrm{Pic}^0_{X}$?
(Or by the universal property we have a family $k_a\colon \mathrm{Pic}^{g-1}_{X_a}\to\mathrm{Alb}(\Theta)$,
could it happen that $\mathrm{Im}(k_a)$ form a moving family that covers $\mathrm{Alb}(\Theta)$? )

Comment: @Sasha If we have a ppav $A$ of dim $\geq2$ with irreducible theta divisor $\Theta$, do we know if  it is true $\mathrm{Alb}(\Theta)=A$?

Comment: @Qixiao: $\Theta \subset A$ is an ample divisor, hence the restriction morphism $$H^1(A,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(\Theta,\mathbb{Z})$$ is an isomorphism by the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, hence $\mathrm{Alb}(\Theta) = A$.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks so much!  (And the compatibility of Hodge structure on the resolution $\mathrm{Sym}^{g-1}(C)$ should be natural by functoriality)

Comment: @Sasha: $\Theta$ can be singular, so one has to be careful when talking about the Albanese.  For Jacobians I think it is known that $\Theta$ has rational singularities, so $\Theta$ and a resolution have the same $h^1(\mathcal O)$.